# Does not conform to protocol 'NSCoding' - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, encoding, nscoding, swift3

I have seen several questions similar to mine; however, those are pertaining to swift 2/1 and I am currently using swift 3. I believe Apple has changed it slightly.

```
class Person: NSObject, NSCoding {

    var signature: UIImage

    init(signature: UIImage) {
        self.signature = signature
    }

    required convenience init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        let signature = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "signature") as! UIImage
        self.init(signature: signature)
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(signature, forKey: "signature")
    }

}
```

You will notice how Swift 3 now forces me to use `required convenience init(` instead of `required init(`. Perhaps that has something to do with it.

How can I resolve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try "Edit -> Convert -> To Current Swift Syntax" in Xcode? That should fix the problem automatically.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The `encode` method in Swift 3 has been renamed to

```
func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder)
```

When you get the *do not conform* error you can easily find out which required methods are missing

- Press <kbd>⌘B</kbd> to build the code.
- Press <kbd>⌘4</kbd> to show the issue navigator.
- Click on the disclosure triangle in front of the issue line.

Comment: Works perfectly. I will accept in 6 minutes once SO let's me do so :)

Comment: I can believe i wasted my 2 precious days just for this.. Hate you swift for such a change.. and love you bro for saving my ass. :) Thanks a lotttt